# How to implement profiles defined by the oasis to be used in SAML

Tags: metadata, saml, profile, xacml, oasis

i am using spring security for implementation of saml, downloaded the sample from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml

Now i want to implement xacml in it, for reference i have been studying SAML 2.0 Profile of XACML and followed http://pushpalankajaya.blogspot.in/2012/02/implementing-saml-to-xacml.html to understand what i need

So basically i got to know that i need to implement the profile defined by oasis

my metadata for service provider is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
entityID="localhost" validUntil="2023-09-23T06:57:15.396Z">
<md:IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned="true"
    protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>MII.....ASWX</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
    <md:SingleLogoutService
        Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
        Location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso" ResponseLocation="https://localhost:9443/samlsso" />
    <md:SingleSignOnService
        Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso" />
    <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP"
        Location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso" ResponseLocation="https://localhost:9433/samlsso" />
    <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent
    </NameIDFormat>
    <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient
    </NameIDFormat>
    <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress
    </NameIDFormat>
    <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified
    </NameIDFormat>
</md:IDPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

I am implementing WSO2 and have defined the PAP and PDP, my request of saml should contain the xacml request specifications as well. Now to use this i found out that "xacml:samlp" namespace i have to implement. As suggested in the blog mentioned above.

So kindly mention how to implement and specify the profile and where i need to set it if in the metadata, or in the WebSSOProfileOptions Bean class defined in the security-context.xml. Thanks in Advance , please help, stuck in this for many days.

Regards,
Joydeep Paul